# export html table to csv in angular 4 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, export-to-csv

Is there a third party component for angular 4 app, which helps in exporting the html table content to csv?

any links / code snippets will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1195569/Angular-Data-Grid-with-Sorting-Filtering-Export-to
take a look at this

Answer (score 0):

You could use this easy to use Module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv

You only have to pass the json list and the name of the generated file.
I already tested it in my application and works perfectly to generate csv files.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my component:

```
public exportDataToCSV(data: Array<Array<any>>,
                           tableHeader: Array<string | number> = []): string {
    const csvData = [];
    if (!!tableHeader.length) {
        data.unshift(tableHeader);
    }
    for (let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; ++i) {
        csvData.push(data[i].join(';'));
    }

    return `data:attachment/csv,${csvData.join('%0A')}`;
}

@ViewChild('exportFileBtn') public exportFileBtn: ElementRef;
private headRows = ['title1', 'title2'];
private rows = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];

public downloadCSV():void {
    this.exportFileBtn.nativeElement.href = 
    this.exportDataToCSV(this.rows, this.columns);
    this.exportFileBtn.nativeElement.click();
}

//HTML
<button (click)="downloadCSV()">Download CSV</button>          
<a #exportFileBtn target="_blank" download="MyCSVFile.csv"></a>
```